# How to run code using the 'gt' library in R with source?

Tags: r, gt

I am a novice at using R and am trying to utilize the "gt" library. Whenever, I run even simple test code with 'source', I cannot get the table to appear. However, when I highlight my code and use 'run' the table appears perfectly. Surely, I'm missing something simple here so any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

I have the same issue running the following simple code, after installing the needed libraries.

```
library(gt)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>% gt()
```

Comment: When I run that code in a script or the console, I get the output table in the Viewer tab of RStudio. What is happening for you?

Comment: If you want to generate an html file (or PDF, or word doc, or pptx...) with a gt table in it, it will be easier with an Rmd or Quarto document than from an R script.

Comment: One option with an R script would be to run knitr::spin("palmer.R"), where palmer.R holds your script -- this will generate markdown and HTML files in your working directory with the output.

Comment: @JonSpring my understanding is that the table should show in the Viewer tab, which does happen when I highlight the code and use the "run" button. I am trying to understand why this action does not occur when I use the "source" button as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this- Save the table as an object and then print the object:

```
library(gt)

library(palmerpenguins)

my_table <- penguins %>% gt()
print(my_table)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue for me. But should the table not show up in the viewer by default?